# Setting property of objects in datacontext

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

all my entities have a common property which specifies the company they belong to, I would like to set this property in a method in my datacontext but I do not want to use the partial methods for each of the entity types that the datacontext provides, is there a method that receives any entity that is inserted throught the datacontext so that I can hook to it or override it and set the property using reflection? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `SubmitChanges` method in your `DataContext` class and then perform necessary changes to your inserted/updated/deleted entities:

```
public partial class YourDataContext
{
    public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        ChangeSet changes = GetChangeSet();

        foreach (var entity in changes.Inserts())
        {
        }

        // you could do the same with updates and deletes

        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    }
}
```